# Design for service discovery of an API

Tags: java, json, api, annotations, hateoas

I am working on a rather large API (390+ functions) and I am trying to pull together all the information that the documentation team would need in order to create docs for the project.

I have decided to use JSON Hyperschema to represent this.

I created an annotation processor to look for all of the `javax.ws.rs.Path` annotation from my code and grab the Javadoc, http method (from annotation) and other parameter information but I am running into a problem.

Hyper schema recommends, and my project spec requires, that the objects sent across an API are to be included as schema in the hyper schema. Typically I would use Jackson to accomplish this. However, as I am in an annotation processor that is not in the main API project, I cannot use class references (ex. `User.class` where user is an object in my API project and not in my processor) without generating errors. (This is explained [here](http://blog.retep.org/2009/02/13/getting-class-values-from-annotations-in-an-annotationprocessor/)).

**My question is, what is the best way around this limitation? I have come up with one way, explained below, but I want this to be pluggable into any other service (of the same format) to document them as well.**

As a solution to this, I have thought to break my generator across compile time and runtime. At compile time I would generate JSON hyperschema with placeholders to reference the object schemas. It would also generate a resource file with full names of all of the objects.

At runtime I was planning on generating the schemas for the returned objects then inserting the links to them into the JSON.

**IMHO this solution doesn't seem very "elegant". Does anyone have any insight into other ways to accomplish this?**

Comment: Which JAX-RS implementation are you using? Have a look at the approach that Jersey uses to generate WADL (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html). You may find it helpful.

Comment: That looks helpful for reading resources I think I may change to that for the resource processing, but I still need to read the javadoc, which will be gone at that point.

Comment: The Jersey team has implemented a doclet that stores the javadoc information for further WADL generation. Have a look: https://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/generate-wadl

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following projects:-

[jsonschema-hypermedia-support](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema#jsonschema-hypermedia-support) which confirms to [enter link description here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html)

OR 
Use Spring HATEOAS 
Also see 
[this stackoveflow thread about Restful API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9219565/2103767)